# Can cookies be set from 4xx responses?

Tags: http, cookies, http-status-code-406

I just tried setting (actually, deleting - via max age set to 0) a session cookie, when I detect a specific client error. The HTTP response I am using is from the 4xx category (e.g. 401, 406, etc).

The cookie deletion works fine with this kind of response generated on the server side:

```
            Response resp = Response.status(Response.Status.OK).header(
                "Set-Cookie",
                cookieName+"="+sessionId+"; "+
                "Version=1; Max-Age=0; Path=" + cookiePath + "; " +
                "Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT").entity("").build();
```

...but fails with this:

```
            Response resp = Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).header(
                "Set-Cookie",
                cookieName+"="+sessionId+"; "+
                "Version=1; Max-Age=0; Path=" + cookiePath + "; " +
                "Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT").entity("").build();
```

(Only difference: 200 => 406).

Is it true that cookies can't be set with 4xx responses?

Comment: Have you tested with multiple browsers? Have you checked in your browser's developer tools if the `Set-Cookie` header is really there? This might be also related to the implementation of the `Response` class.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) states that those cookies **MUST** be accepted:

> Origin servers MAY send a Set-Cookie response header with any
> response.  User agents MAY ignore Set-Cookie headers contained in
> responses with 100-level status codes but MUST process Set-Cookie
> headers contained in other responses (including responses with 400-
> and 500-level status codes).  An origin server can include multiple
> Set-Cookie header fields in a single response.  The presence of a
> Cookie or a Set-Cookie header field does not preclude HTTP caches
> from storing and reusing a response.

Comment: I knew it was weird - thanks for certifying that this looks like a browser bug (I am coding with Firefox26/Linux).